# C Heap Allocation Indexing / Access

Tags: c, winapi

I believe I have a very basic pointer question... I am wanting to use Windows APIs (so things like malloc are out of the question) to create a dynamic block of memory to use for various things, save C strings, integer values, etc. at various offsets within the allocated area.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
HANDLE hProcess = NULL;
LONG32 *lpHeapAddr = NULL;

hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
lpHeapAddr = (LONG32*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 0xC00);
```

My question is, how can I access specific offsets within the returned space.  The variable  *lpHeapAddr* contains the base address of the memory allocation.  I suspected *lpHeapAddr[0x10]* would give me access to the 16th offset into this allocation. But I'm finding things like this aren't working and I suspect it's simply because my logic or understanding is incorrect:

```
char some_array[] = {0xED, 0x84, 0x5A, 0x20};

for(i = 0; i < 0x04; i++){
  lpHeapAddr[0x30+i] = some_array[i];   
}
```

The values in *lpHeapAddr[0x30]* are not the values in *some_array*.

Hopefully this is clear as to what my confusion is, as always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Should be HANDLE, not Handle. should be LONG32* lpHeapAdr (missing*). Show real code, and where exactly it breaks.

Comment: The values at that particular offset in the for loop are not as expected... is this the correct way to index and increment through the memory addresses?

Comment: yes.it is pointer to allocated memory block

Comment: Show real code please... Works OK for me (values at lpHeapAddr[0x30] correctly copied from another source)

Comment: he got cast problems. assigning char to int . wait i post you working codes.

Comment: Indexing a `LONG32*` pointer allows you to only step in increments of `sizeof(LONG32)`, which should be 4 bytes. When you want byte granularity, use `char*`.

Comment: But what's the point of having used LONG32* if it's not precisely to have that 4 bytes granularity???

Comment: @manuell I suppose he wants to read one `LONG32` at a time, but write one `char` at a time. Using `LONG32*` is of little use in the second use case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be aware of pointer math;

```
type *pointer ;
pointer+index; // address=pointer+sizeof(type)*index
pointer[index] // address=pointer+sizeof(type)*index
++pointer ;    // address=pointer+sizeof(type)
```

Here is code:

```
char *memchar_addr=(char*)(lpHeapAddr[0x30]);
                    for(i = 0; i < 0x04; i++){
                      memAddr[i] = some_array[i];
                      printf("%c\t",memAddr[i]);
                    }
```

Here is full code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "windows.h" 
int main()
{

    HANDLE hHeap;           // heap handle
    hHeap=GetProcessHeap();
    char some_array[0x3F];
    memset(some_array,(int)65,sizeof(some_array));
    if (hHeap!=NULL)
    {
        int *memAddr=NULL;  //pointer to memory
        memAddr=(int*)HeapAlloc(hHeap,0,0xC00);
        if (memAddr!=NULL)
        {
               int i;
             for(i = 0; i < 0x3F; i++){
                  memAddr[0x20+i] = some_array[i];
                  printf("%d\t",memAddr[0x20+i]);
             }
            char some_array2[] = {0xED, 0x84, 0x5A, 0x20};

                    for(i = 0; i < 0x04; i++){
                      memAddr[0x30+i] =(int) some_array2[i];
                      printf("%d\t",memAddr[0x30+i]);
                    }

            if (HeapFree(hHeap,0,memAddr)==0)
                printf("free error");
        }

    }
}
```